# .NET ConfigurationManager app.config confusion

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I've got an app.config file, which contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name ="PowershellSnapIns" type ="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler,System"/>
    </configSections>

    <PowershellSnapIns>
        <add key="SnapIn1" value="WebAdministration" />
        <add key="SnapIn2" value="Jimmy Hendrix" />
        <add key="SnapIn3" value="..." />
    </PowershellSnapIns>
</configuration>
```

I was going to use the ConfigurationSettings class to read it, but that has been deprecated. That was fairly simple to use. Now I have to use the ConfigurationManager class, and I now have this code to read it.

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration config =
     ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

IDictionary SnapInList = (IDictionary) config.GetSection("PowershellSnapIns");
```

But it keeps erroring out. I changed the app.config properties to copy across to the build, but it keeps accepting that it can't find the file. The exception says it's looking for 
`TestConsole.vshost.exe.config`. Does vs2k8sp1 now rename the app.config for you automatically, and if so, what am I doing wrong? Surely I don't need to rename the app.config file to debug vhost. I do know in release that it's probably being renamed `TestConsole.exe.config`. So what's going wrong? Is it the case of the code wrong or what?

Comment: .NET doesn't "error out". It throws exceptions. When an exception is uncaught, and causes your program to "not work", you should post the complete exception in your question. Catch the exception, then post the results of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: will do. I tried renaming the file to TestConsole.vhost.exe.config but it came back empty.

Comment: Hi John,
This is the exception. 
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for PowershellSnapI
ns: Could not load file or assembly 'System' or one of its dependencies. The sys
tem cannot find the file specified. (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Stu
dio 2008\Projects\TestConsole\TestConsole\bin\Debug\TestConsole.vshost.exe.confi
g line 4)

Comment: I removed the ,System from the section name, and it now reads
 <section name ="PowershellSnapIns" type ="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
 
I now get the exception.

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'Sys
tem.Collections.IDictionary'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

-Make sure that `System` and `System.Configuration.dll` are available in your bin directory. You do this by adding the reference to both dlls and set their `copy local` attribute to `true`.

-Make sure in your `App.Config` file, set the `copy local` attributes to `false`.

-Use the following method:

```
public static string XMLCheck
{
    get
    {
        var section =(Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PowershellSnapIns");
        return (string)section["SnapIn1"];

    }
}
```

-The `XMLCheck` should return "`WebAdministration`"

Comment: The key doesn't matter, since I don't need to know the key, just the value, which is is the powershell snapin name.

Comment: Hi Ngu Soon Hui, 
It worked. Thanks. I can see now (hindsight is beautiful) that the ConfigurationManager class is static. Thanks.

Comment: Works with a cast to `(NameValueCollection)` for me.

Answer (score 1):

VS renames the app.config to yourappname.exe and places it in the bin directory along with your .exe

Can you confirm that the file exists in the bin directory along with your exe.

Comment: The file TestConsole.vhost.exe.config is in the Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestConsole\TestConsole\bin\Debug directory.