# GetSection object cannot be cast to IDictionary<>

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configurationsection

I hope I'm just missing something simple. I need to read/write to a section of my exe.config file. I have this in my code:

```
var appConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Mytest.Console.exe");
var fileEnvironment = appConfiguration.GetSection("fileEnvironment");
```

and this is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="fileEnvironment" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    </configSections>

    <fileEnvironment>
        <add key="TestEntry1" value="A nice value"/>
        <add key="TestEntry2" value="Another value"/>
    </fileEnvironment>
</configuration>
```

My appConfiguration variable is returned as {System.Configuration.Configuration} and the "HasFile" property is set to true.

Without casting my variable "fileEnvironment" is returned as `System.Configuration.DefaultSection`. When I add as `IDictionary<string, string>` to the `GetSection` method fileEnvironment is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: GetSection returns a ConfigurationSection, not a Dictionary, so nothing strange about that. What are you expecting to be able to do with the fileEnvironment variable?

Comment: Have you check out this previous quesntion and answer...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278730/net-configurationmanager-app-config-confusion

Comment: Yes, I read through that one. That's where I learned about DictionarySectionHandler. Anyway, I want to extract the entire fileEnvironment section as a dictionary, modify some parts of it, and save the entire dictionary back to the configuration file. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why not create your own custom configuartion setting this is probably a better method to use? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: How do I pass the entire dictionary around to the rest of my application. I was hoping to add new entries to the dictionary and insert the new entries into the config file. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I kept researching the dictionary issue and came up with [this stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935331/how-to-implement-a-configurationsection-with-a-configurationelementcollection)! It produces a collection instead of a dictionary, but points the way to a solution. Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept researching the dictionary issue and came up with [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935331/how-to-implement-a-configurationsection-with-a-configurationelementcollection)! It produces a collection instead of a dictionary, but points the way to a solution. Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903356.aspx), when a section is implemented using [`DictionarySectionHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dictionarysectionhandler.aspx), [`ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) will return a non-generic [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx), and **not** an [`IDictionary<T,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx). That's why your cast failed.

Although in modern times, it looks like it actually returns a [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).